# Android and IOS expecting different resource paths (Cordova)

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I'm using Cordova to create an app for android and ios, however when building it for android, it gives me `Error: Source path does not exist: res/icon/ios/icon.png`

The problem is it wants the path to be `www/res/icon/ios/icon.png`, which works but then ios build breaks!  Why does android even care about the ios path?  I've tried different versions of android and cordova, both give me the same error.

Here is the line in my config file:  `<icon gap:platform="ios" height="60" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="60" />` .

Oh and I'm not using Ionic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to using specific versions of cordova android and ios:

`Android:  6.3.0`
`ios:  4.0.0`

As well as changing the android paths to include `www/` at the beginning. Building for ios shows warnings when doing this, but at least it builds and works fine unlike android which refused to build.

But when building with phonegap then no `www/` is needed in the path.. can't explain why cordova can't build on my macbook exclusively with other platform versions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you confirmed/checked your config.xml with the official [doc](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/images.html)

Please check you have added correct slash:

```
<icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
```

Check your folder structure. Have you added any extra folder in the path?

Comment: I've remade the config.xml twice with correct slashes, and my folder structure is fine.  It builds on my desktop and windows laptop but not mac.  I've already fixed it though, it was a weird version problem..

Comment: @Seb Cool. Happy coding.